# grunt scripts.postinstall of package.json can't be placed in a subdirectory?

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs

Is there a reason why "./bin/post_install.sh" and "bin/post_install.sh" would fail in scripts.postinstall of package.json? Works fine in the root directory, but that will quickly become a nightmare as more executable etc are added.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./bin/post_install.sh"
},
```

and

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bin/post_install.sh"
},
```

both throw errors over "." or "bin" not being recognized as an internal or external command? But the examples on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) show "scripts/file.js" as an example???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I'm using windows so have to use \.  Hopefully this helps someone.

Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bin\\post_install.sh"
},
```